# How could we implement broadcast variables in PySpark without making use of a UDF function? For generating a new column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, optimization, user-defined-functions, azure-synapse

I've been exploring implementation of Broadcast variables where I have a column named 'State_Code' in my sample dataset. I want to make use of broadcast variables to make this like `'CA':'California', 'NJ' : 'New Jersey'`

I've implemented the below code in spark and it does what it need to create a new column

```py
val = {"CA": "California", "NY": "New York", "NJ": "New Jersey"}


broad = sc.broadcast(val)

def broad_function(a):
    return broad.value[a]


broad_udf = udf(broad_function)

df.withColumn('State_Name',broad_udf('State_code')).show()
```

The above serves the purpose of creating new column with State Names, but using UDF wouldn't utilise the spark Optimisation. The whole purpose of using broadcast variables is for optimisation, how could we make use of broadcast variables to create a new column without making use of UDF and without converting this into an RDD ?

I tried using when , col however those wouldn't make use of broadcast variables.  Expecting to create a new column using broadcast variables without making use of UDF in dataframes

Comment: Could you please help me with a sample dataframe and the output too.

Comment: Its actually not related to dataframe and the output , I would like to understand if there is any alternate procedure that we can use to define the broadcast variables , as you can see in the above code that I used with UDF which works, but using UDF again wont benefit the spark optimisation

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this and UDF is often not the choice to go ahead with.

I am not 100% sure if you wanted to have such an answer or not, Do let me know if your objective was different.

So this approach is based on using Spark Config `autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`.

**STEP 1 : Convert HashMap/Dict to a dataframe**

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType,StructField,StructType}

spark.conf.set("autoBroadcastJoinThreshold",104857600)

def convertHashMapToDataframe(hash:HashMap[String,String],keyCol:String,valueCol:String):DataFrame = { 
      val rows = hash.toSeq.map { case (keyCol,valueCol) => Row(keyCol,valueCol) }
      val convertedRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows)
      val schema = StructType(Seq(
        StructField(keyCol,StringType,true),
        StructField(valueCol,StringType,true)
      ))
      val df = spark.createDataFrame(convertedRDD,schema=schema)
      df
}

val states = HashMap("CA"->"California", "NY"-> "New York", "NJ"-> "New Jersey")


val state_df = convertHashMapToDataframe(state_dict,"code","name")
state_df.show()

+----+----------+
|code|      name|
+----+----------+
|  NJ|New Jersey|
|  NY|  New York|
|  CA|California|
+----+----------+

val data = Seq((11,"CA","Jose"),(21,"NJ","Shaun"),(113,"NY","Terry")).toDF("id","state_code","name")
data.show()

+---+----------+-----+
| id|state_code| name|
+---+----------+-----+
| 11|        CA| Jose|
| 21|        NJ|Shaun|
|113|        NY|Terry|
+---+----------+-----+
```

**STEP 2 : Enable the config followed by joining**

```
val result = data.join(
                      broadcast(state_df),
                      col("state_code")===col("code"),
                      "left"
                      )
result.show()

+---+----------+-----+----+----------+
| id|state_code| name|code|      name|
+---+----------+-----+----+----------+
| 11|        CA| Jose|  CA|California|
| 21|        NJ|Shaun|  NJ|New Jersey|
|113|        NY|Terry|  NY|  New York|
+---+----------+-----+----+----------+
```

I hope this gives you another perspective to solve the problem. I would be updating this answer to come up with a few more ways.

References -

[SparkByExamplesLink](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/broadcast-join-in-spark/#:%7E:text=Spark%20Broadcast%20Join%20is%20an,can%20perform%20a%20join%20without)